# Child object failed to save in one-to-many bi-direction relation

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have one to many relation with Location and TradeLocation class.I have tried every bit of alternative but still insertion failed in child class(TradeLocation).
Following is the code and the stack trace which i got now :

```
//Parent Class
@Entity
@Table(name="location")
public class Location implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;


    private String name;
    private Long stateId;
    private Long districtId;
    private Long cityId;
    private Long zoneId;
    @Column(name="yearEstablishment")
    private String yearOfEstablishment;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="location")
    @Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Set<TradeLocation>tradeLocation=new HashSet<TradeLocation>(0);

    /*getter and setter*/
}

//Child class
@Entity
@Table(name = "trade_location")
public class TradeLocation implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;


    /*@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)*/
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="tradeId")
    private Trade trade;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    /*@Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL})*/
    @JoinColumn(name="locationId",nullable = false)
    private Location location;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private TradeStatus status;

    //getter and setter
}
```

Stack Trace :

```
Hibernate: insert into location (cityId, districtId, name, stateId, yearEstablishment, zoneId)  values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into trade_location (locationId, status, tradeId) values (?, ?, ?)
[ WARN] [http-bio-8080-exec-2 10:07:56] (SqlExceptionHelper.java:logExceptions:143) SQL Error: 1048, SQLState: 23000
[ERROR] [http-bio-8080-exec-2 10:07:56] (SqlExceptionHelper.java:logExceptions:144) Column 'locationId' cannot be null

//Insertion Code :
Session session =   sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
session.saveOrUpdate(location);
```

Comment: Please show you insertion logic and how you create your objects.

Comment: I dont see locationId column in your mapping file, is it mapped properly?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I have added insertion code too.I have tried every thing but still its child object is not saving.Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Zeus : locationId is the foreign key in TradeLocation table and i have mapped it as object.Please see in TradeLocation class. Thanks